# how to use new table as a foreign key in existing table in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Hi Everyone i have two  model 1 in Dailytrip and 2nd one is Team, i need to use Team model as foreign key  in Dailytrip model, while run Makemigrations getting error. i am using django-2.2 and python 3.7

**Models.py**

```
class DailyTrip(BaseModel):
    date = models.DateField(default=None)
    Team=models.ForeignKey(
        Team,
        models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='Team',
        null=True,
        default=None
    )

class Team(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**Error**

```
class DailyTrip(BaseModel):
  File "E:\11-march-2022\everest_jarvis\fleet\models.py", line 595, in DailyTrip
    Team,
NameError: name 'Team' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this happens is because you define the `ForeignKey` before you define `Team`. You can define `Team` first, so:

```
class Team(BaseModel):
    # …
    pass

class DailyTrip(BaseModel):
    # …
    Team = models.ForeignKey(
        Team,
        models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='Team',
        null=True,
        default=None
    )
```

or if that is not possible, use a string literal:

```
class DailyTrip(BaseModel):
    # …
    Team = models.ForeignKey(
        'Team',
        models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='Team',
        null=True,
        default=None
    )

class Team(BaseModel):
    # …
```

---

> **Note**: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PascalCase*, so it should be: `team` instead of <s>`Team`</s>.